# Zoom-to-fit in preview application when viewing pdf full screen

Tags: pdf, preview, fullscreen

Several generations of OSX ago, it was possible to view PDFs full-screen in Preview, and they would automatically fit to the screen, which was great for PDF presentations (e.g. Beamer, or PDF-exported PowerPoint). Now, either when using Slideshow or Full Screen, I get these black or gray borders that I can't seem to get rid of (screenshots, first is Slideshow, second is Full Screen):
[image: Slideshow view]

[image: Full Screen view]

Is there any way to revert to the old style, fit-to-screen, or should I just resort to 3rd-party applications like [Présentation](http://iihm.imag.fr/blanch/software/osx-presentation/)?

Note: I am using OSX High Sierra.

Comment: It seems your screen's width is larger than its height, so what behavior are you expecting? Fit to width and have the top and bottom stripped off? Perhaps you could configure your beamer to prepare slides in 16/9 format and that may fit the screen better?! It currently seems to be 4/3. Try `\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}`. That fills up the screen for me.

Comment: It's guaranteed that there will be letterboxing on the sides, rather, I am trying to avoid the unnecessary borders along the top and bottom. I have used the aspectratio option before, and while it does let me fill more of the screen, there are still excess borders on all sides (even when viewing a 16/9 pdf on a 16/9 screen), which honestly still makes the presentation look strange. At this point I am beginning to think 3rd-party is the only way to go.